# Android Widget lost from view if the list is to long

Tags: android, listview

I have the following layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical">

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:longClickable="true"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/notes"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

The TextView is populated programmatically and is shown at the bottom of the list as I require however when the list starts to fill the screen the TextView is list behind the list and can no longer be seen. How can I stop the List view expanding into the space occupied by the text view?

I was thinking about changing it to a ScrollView but is was my understanding that you shouldn't use a ListView inside a ScrollView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a RelativeLayout Instead Of LinearLayout

and add this to your ListView

```
<ListView
...
android:layout_above="@+id/notes"
/>
```

if you want the textView To be at the bottom of your view add this too:

```
 android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

Comment: That's just what I needed. I did need to add  android:layout_alignParentTop="true" to my list view so that when it was not filling the screen the white space was under it not above it.